# Unable to update record in brightstar database

Tags: c#, in-memory-database

Not sure if anybody in community has got a chance to work on Inmemory database(bright star) well I am trying to update a record through code below but unable to do so.

```
    public void ChangePrice(string strId)
    {
        string configTDDB = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TDSDB"];
        double Price = 10.10;
        IMDB.IMDBEntityContext TDcontext = new IMDB.IMDBEntityContext(configTDDB);

        var claim = bdcontext.Price_Lists.FirstOrDefault<TDParser.IMDB.IPrice_List>(m               => m.NDC == strId);
        claim.Price = Price;
        TDContext.SaveChanges(); 

    }
```

Any suggestion/help on this would be of great help.

Comment: do they have documentation/working samples, i'd start with that.

Comment: http://www.brightstardb.com/documentation/Developing_With_BrightstarDB2.html#Basics

Comment: Could it just be that you name your context as `bdcontext`, then later call `TDContext.SaveChanges()`.  Meaning you are making changes in one context, then saving another?

Comment: please ignore that as I have replaced all the prod code var/ constant with prefix td..

Answer (score 0):

Hi Team,
                 Thanks for your response to this thread I have find the reason for not allowing to perofrm CRUD operation - it was licesencing issue and now I am able to updat using the same above code.